# ECS Task container performance plummets after an hour of processing

Tags: php, performance, resources, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm not sure what's happening here, but about an hour in of running, my task resources plummet:

[image: View of resource usage]

It's been pretty consistent throughout all my tests within ECS. When I run this container on my local system, it takes about 3 hours. On ECS, it starts off well, then it's processing plummets at ~1hr and takes 12 hours to complete. That last tail spike is the export process (exporting tables and data).

The key elements here: it completes. It has way more than enough resources. It's a series of two containers: php script; mysql db (side-car).

On my local system, the PHP script runs at ~85mg RAM for the entire time. On ECS, I have gave it 1G(!), and it has a full vCPU. It certainly is *not* related to resource allocations. I can't figure out what's going on. I'm using the **same** source DB for remote and local.

Any ideas on what to troubleshoot?

Specifics:

- ECS Fargate
- PHP Container runs php artisan command that reads a remote db, massages data, and stores it in a side-car mysql db
- Then it exports data and pushes it to S3
- There are no volume definitions - everything is internal to the container(s).
- Task has 2vCPU, 4GB RAM - 1vCPU on PHP and MySQL, 1GB RAM on PHP, 3GB on MySQL -- way, way more than necessary and this still happens

Initially, it takes about 3 seconds to process 500 rows. Eventually, at the end, it takes upwards of 30+ seconds to process 500 rows. Locally, it remains at a consistent, 3 seconds at start and 3 seconds at the end.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't missing an index on the database that is running in ECS? Since you are running MySQL in a container like this, without any volumes, it is going to be recreating the entire database each time you run this. If you are missing something in that database creation like an index that you have locally, then that could be the issue. This sounds exactly like you are performing a non-indexed query on the database as part of your processing job, and as more and more data is added to the database that query is taking longer and longer.

Comment: My local process is using the same database source. It "should" be slower locally with network latency (as ECS runs in the same network as the source DB).  The query is using the PK for the order clause on the limit call: select * limit 500 order by pk. The destination is a fresh DB, fresh table creation on both runs (local and ecs).